# how to parse xml output and get value of an element/sub-element under a specific tag in robot framework

Tags: xml, robotframework

I'm trying to parse the following xml output and get the element and sub-element for the tags using robot framework. I want to get a specific value for example "adjacency-state" for level 2. Since there are multiple identical tags, how can i achieve that.

Example:

```
<isis-adjacency-information>
<isis-adjacency>
    <interface-name>xe-0/0/2:0.0</interface-name>
    <system-name>st-48s-p2-31</system-name>
    <level>1</level>
    <adjacency-state>Up</adjacency-state>
    <holdtime>8</holdtime>
    <snpa>88:e0:f3:1c:a0:7</snpa>
</isis-adjacency>
<isis-adjacency>
    <interface-name>xe-0/0/2:0.0</interface-name>
    <system-name>st-48s-p2-31</system-name>
    <level>2</level>
    <adjacency-state>Up</adjacency-state>
    <holdtime>6</holdtime>
    <snpa>88:e0:f3:1c:a0:7</snpa>
</isis-adjacency>
</isis-adjacency-information>
```

Below code fetches the value for the first xpath match. But I need the adjacency state under level 2.

```
${cmd0}=    Execute    Commands Executor    @{target}[0]    command=show isis adjacency    format=xml    xpath=//adjacency-state
```

Any suggestions/ideas are welcome.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Elementtree has limited support for predicates. So rather than use a complex XPath, you can iterate over the elements, looking for the appropriate one. Here is a solution that is a bit noisy as far as the test log goes, but does work:

```
${xml}    Parse Xml    /path/to/example.xml
@{adjacencies}    Get Elements    ${xml}    isis-adjacency
${state}    Set Variable    NOT FOUND
:FOR    ${adjacency}    IN    @{adjacencies}
\    ${level}    Get Element Text    ${adjacency}    level
\    ${state}    Set Variable If    '${level}'=='2'    ${level}    ${state}
\    Exit For Loop If    '${level}'=='2'
Should Not Be Equal    ${state}    NOT FOUND    Did not find state for adjacency of level 2
Log    State is ${state}
```

Comment: This was assuming that every isis-adjacency element has a child called level. Otherwise you would get an error and use a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 1):

My case Error "No element matching" was appearing for webservice "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx"  so I wrote my code like this

```
${XML_object}=  Parse XML  ${soap_response}
     log    ${XML_object}
     ${result}=  get element text  ${XML_object}  .//AddResult
```